# Troubles with downloading

Tags: python, get, python-requests

I has wrote script for one site. But, links to download files at this site aren't primary and call some PHP script. How can I download file?

It is a script for one minecraft site with mods. I just want to download files, not PHP script.

Comment: How is the PHP script called? Maybe you could show us the website you are talking about?

Comment: https://ru-m.org/mody-minecraft/18 @Silveris

Comment: You want to download the .jar files?

Comment: Yes @MarsNebulaSoup